# how do i add the sort extension to the IMAP server?

Tags: java, email, imap, web-applications

If we do own a Mail server supporting, how is it possible to add a sort extension to it ?

Also how is it possible for a client using java mail to check if the server does indeed support the Sort extension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an extension will be dependent on the IMAP server in question, and probably a question for [Serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: +1 for the suggestion,

is it possible for the client to know if the server supports the SORT function ?

Comment: If I telnet to an IMAP server (port 143) its status line gives me info on what it can do. I don't know if this is reflected in the JavaMail API, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to detect the support of SORT extension. Connect to the server and issue the CAPABILITY command. Ie. "telnet example.org 143" and then write "A0 CAPABILITY"<enter>.

Comment: Can you determine capability via the JavaMail API though ?